# Google places api I want to get JSON output

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I want to search for locations in a particular place on the google places api and display them on JSOn output.Suppose I want to search for all the banks my near place. How do I code for that.Can you please give sample code.

Comment: Please read the Google Places API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 0):

try this working code..it uses jquery mobile. it finds the places around your current lat & lon.

map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />


  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>   
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>   
  <script src="js/map.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="none" class="page-map" id="page-map">
  <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>
    <div id="map-canvas">
                        <!-- map loads here... -->
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

map.js

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var lat;
var lng;
var lng;
var service;
var reference;
var initialLocation;

$( '.page-map' ).live( 'pagecreate',function(event){        
    checkLocation();
});


function checkLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;

            callPlaceService(lat, lng);
        }, gpsFail, {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            maximumAge : 300000
        });
    }
}

function callPlaceService(lat, lng) {

    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom : 15,
        center : pyrmont,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    var request = {
        location : pyrmont,
        radius : 5000,
        //types: ['atm','bank'],
        keyword : 'Bank'
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);    
    service.search(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var requestDetails = {reference : results[i].reference};

            service.getDetails(requestDetails, checkDetailedStatus);
        }
    }
}

function checkDetailedStatus(details, detailStatus) {
    if (detailStatus == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        var name = '{"name":"'+  details.name +'"}';
        var address = '{"address":"' + details.formatted_address + '"}'; 
        var phone = '{"phone":"' + details.formatted_phone_number+ '"}';        
        var website = '{"website":"' + details.website + '"}';
        var full_address = name + "," + address + "," + phone + "," + website;  
        console.log(full_address);
        var jsonTxt = JSON.stringify(full_address);

    } 
}

function gpsFail() {
    //Geo-location is supported, but we failed to get your coordinates. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving code.I am using android tablet.i need java script aplictaion using phonegap for google maps.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=13.117730,80.148430&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=yourkey).

Here you need to give radius according to your distance. Types may be ATM, Restaurants, Gas Station the way you needs.

You need to give places like Chennai, Bangalore, etc or you provide latitude/longitude. Describe it briefly. You in android/iphone